# Моя Родина / Своя Родина

Tags: грамотная-речь, лексика

Правильно ли употреблять " Моя Родина" / "Своя Родина " или это является речевой ошибкой?

Comment: Вы имеете в виду именно такую запись через косую черту?

Comment: Нет,я имею ввиду речевую ошибку ,связанную со значением этих слов. Может ли быть "Родина моя". Человек должен любить *свою Родину. *

Comment: В именительном падеже (моя родина) - безусловно, может. Но выражение "_я люблю **мою** родину_" косвенно указывает на то, что говорящий считает родину принадлежащей лично себе. Такое возможно разве что в речи диктатора, который любит родину иначе, чем подданные (ему она "принадлежит" больше), но это звучит комично.

Comment: Из словаря:  МОЙ,  1. Принадлежащий мне, свойственный мне. Мой дом. Моя книга.  // Исходящий от меня; осуществляемый, производимый мной.  Мой совет. Моё письмо.  // Переживаемый, испытываемый мною.  Мои чувства.  2. Связанный со мной отношениями родства, дружбы и т.п. Мои друзья.  Моя семья.  // Руководимый мною. Моя бригада. Мой класс. // Такой, к которому я ПРИНАДЛЕЖУ, частью которого я являюсь. Моя РОДИНА. Мой завод.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Это моя родина.  *Я люблю **мою** Родину.*  В данном случае  ***мой***  – это такой, к которому я принадлежу, частью которого я являюсь.  **Притяжательное** местоимение ***мой***  соотносится с личным местоимением я. Выбор варианта **соотносится** с контекстом и художественной задачей автора.
2. **Возвратно-притяжательное** местоимение ***свой*** может относиться ко всем трем лицам: Человек должен любить свою родину.  *Я люблю **свою** Родину*. Они любят свою Родину. Вы тоже любите свою Родину.
3. *Я люблю **мою/свою** Родину*.

Возможно синонимическое употребление притяжательных местоимений ***мой – свой***. В подобных случаях возвратное местоимение  ***свой*** следует относить к слову, называющему **производителя** соответствующего действия.
Выбор варианта **соотносится** с контекстом и художественной задачей автора.

**Розенталь:** Возможно синонимическое употребление притяжательных местоимений ***мой – свой, твой – свой*** и т.п. Ср.: ... Я предаюсь ***моим*** мечтам (Пушкин). – Я не потерплю в ***своем*** доме воров (Чехов). Употребление притяжательных местоимений ***мой, твой, наш, ваш*** вместо возможного по условиям контекста ***свой*** больше подчеркивает связь с соответствующим лицом, **в частности** при противопоставлении, например: ***Моей*** главы коснись ***твоей*** рукой (Жуковский).

http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/60.htm

**Примеры из Нацкорпуса:**

Само собой понятно, что ***я люблю мою родину***, Россию, и раз на нее напали, то будь это хоть дурак или сумасшедший, я должен защищать ее, не щадя этого своего живота. [Л. Н. Андреев. (1916)]

Для кого покинул ***я мою родину***, уехал из Ясс, расстался с родными?.. [М. Н. Загоскиния (1848)]

Очень люблю Кавказ, ***люблю мою родину***, люблю тебя, Лилия, ― и как люблю! [А. А. Бестужев-Марлинский. (1835-1836)]

Таким образом, в этом предложении возможны **оба варианта**, но местоимение ***мой*** усиливает значение притяжательности.

Comment: Розенталь допускает замену "своей" на "моей" (с целью "большего подчеркивания принадлежности"), но не в _произвольном_ контексте. В качестве примера подходящего контекста он упоминает _противопоставление_, а остальные примеры приводит из поэтических текстов, - они обычно допускают вольности. Мне выражение "Я люблю **мою** родину" кажется _неестественным_ (как минимум, для любого прозаического текста) - возможно, потому, что "усиленная" принадлежность здесь ассоциируется с утверждением "мою, а не чью нибудь ещё". Такого не происходит в выражении "я люблю мою собаку".